# Using Ramsey theory to show some properties of subgraph of a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

> Let $r > 1$ be an integer. Prove that there is an integer $n_0$ such
>   that for every integer $n\geq n_0$ and every directed graph $G = (\{1,...,n\}, E)$ without loops, $G$ has an induced subgraph $H$ with
>   $r$ vertices and $H$ is a linear/total order **OR** $H$ has no
>   directed edges at all, **OR** $H$ has edges in both directions between
>   any two distinct vertices.
>
> **Hints:** Find a appropriate 4-coloring of $[\{1,...,n\}]^2$ and use the Ramsey number $R(2,4,r)$

I don't really know where to start to be honest. I guess I show use *the* Ramsey theorem in some form but I'm confused because I can't find any examples or figuring out by myself how to use it when I have a directed graph to begin with.

How can I show that a subgraph in the above case must have any of these three properties as above?

Any help would be highly appreciated. I wish I could present more effort on my part but I really find Ramsey theory quite challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that if  $n = R(2,4,r)$  then any 4-coloring of the edges of the complete graph $K_n$ yields a monochromatic $K_r$.

Let $G$ be a directed graph on $n = R(2,4,r)$ vertices. Now consider the coloring $c$ of the edges of $K_n$ as follow:

$c(\{i, j\}) = \begin{cases} 0 & (i,j) \notin E(G) \text{ and }  (j,i) \notin E(G) \\
1 & i \lt j \text{ and } (i,j) \in E(G)\\
2 & i \lt j \text{ and } (j,i) \in E(G)\\
3 & (i,j) \in E(G) \text{ and }  (j,i) \in E(G)
\end{cases}$

By the definition of $n$, we must have a monochromatic $K_r$. If the color of $K_r$ is $0$ then we have an $H$ with no directed edges, if it is $1$ or $2$ we have an $H$ which is a total order and if it is $3$ we have an $H$ with edges in both directions.

Comment: I think I made this problem very much harder in head then it actually was. I need to step back and check my premises more often. Thank you very much for providing an excellent answer!